# How to express that a child must pass all grade 1 subjects to study in grade 2?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

A child is not allowed to study in grade 2 if he/she has not passed all required grade-1 subjects.

Is it correct to say

> you won't pass your class if you don't pass all the required subjects

or

> you won't pass your grade if you don't pass all the required subjects

I heard some Americans say "pass your class" but couldn't find that phrase in dictionaries and I am not sure if British people say that too.

I am wonder if "pass your grade" is correct.

What about "move up to higher grade"?

**What is the phrase to express a student who didn't pass his class?** For example, "he repeated his class", "he repeated his class twice"?

Comment: It is not said much in British English, since English education is based on years, not grades.  You can't get held back in the English system.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question the language I typically encounter is "advance": "You won't advance to 2nd grade if you don't learn this math."

For the last, in typical US usage at least that is called "held back": "John was held back a year in 4th grade."

Comment: I thought "the 2nd grade", "the 4th grade" sound better